# Angular Material 2 How to close md-menu on mouseleave

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using Angular Material 2 to create a menu with md-menu component.
I want to close menu on mouse leave. 
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your global Angular styles. (`.scss`)

```
.mat-menu-panel {
  &.mouseleave {
    .mat-menu-content {
      padding: 0;
      > div {
        padding-top: 8px;
        padding-bottom: 8px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Add this to your component class:

```
  @ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger) menuTrigger: MatMenuTrigger;

...

  closeMenu() {
    this.menuTrigger.closeMenu();
  }
```

Create an HTML menu like this:
(Add the class "mouseleave" to your `mat-menu` element.)

```
  <mat-menu class="mouseleave" #menu="matMenu">
    <div (mouseleave)="closeMenu()">
      <button mat-menu-item>1</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>2</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>3</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>4</button>
    </div>
  </mat-menu>
```

Comment: The mat-menu  mouseleave event is not working in angular/material--6.3.1

Answer (score 4):

You can use closeMenu() from the MaterialMenuTigger but it will not work if you put is just on the menu. If you wrapp a span around all buttons and add (mouseleave) to the spann it will work.

My solution for the problem was.

```
<button md-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<md-menu #menu="mdMenu" >
  <span (mouseleave)="trigger.closeMenu()>
    <button md-menu-item>Item 1</button>
    <button md-menu-item>Item 2</button>
  </span>
</md-menu>
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" #trigger="matMenuTrigger">Menu</button>
```

Comment: Since mat-menu-content has padding-top and padding-bottom: 8px, you can get very funky behavior with this method where the menu may seem to flicker

Answer (score 0):

You can take leverage of the `closeMenu()` method from the [Material Menu API](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api) and execute it on mouse leave as follows:

```
<button md-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<md-menu #menu="mdMenu" (mouseleave)="menu.closeMenu()">
  <button md-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button md-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</md-menu>
```

Should work.

Comment: This doesn't work because of the way Angular removes that host element from the DOM on rendering the menu